# How to make distinction between columns in table and make the table slightly smaller

Tags: tables, formatting

How do I make a clear distinction between the $M_1$ and $M_2$ columns in this table. Also, if it is possible, how do I make the table slightly smaller?

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!]
\caption{Results} % title name of the table
\centering % centering table
\begin{tabular}{l rrr rrrrrr} % creating 10 columns
\hline\hline % inserting double-line
 &\multicolumn{3}{c}{$M_1$}  &\multicolumn{6}{c}{$M_2$}
\\ [0.5ex]
\hline 
$i$ & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ [0.5ex]
$r_i$ & 170 & 0 & 130 & 170 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 130 & 0 \\ [0.5ex]
$\int_0^T g_i(x(t))$ & 204178.8 & 580.7 & 580.7 & 45840.7 & 158338.1 & 580.7 & 0 & 580.7 & 0 \\
 [1ex] 
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this?

[image]

(red lines show page layout). for this table i use packages `booktabs` for horizontal rules, `makecell` for more vertical space around cells' contents and `siunitx` for `S` columns which enable aligning numbers at decimal points.

table width is prescribed with `tabular*` to text width. separation between columns is automatically adjusted by `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\caption{Results} % title name of the table
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                    >{$}l<{$}
                        S[table-format=6.1]
                   *{2}{S[table-format=3.1]}
                        S[table-format=5.1]
                        S[table-format=6.1]
                   *{2}{S[table-format=3.1]
                        S[table-format=1.0]}
                    } % creating 10 columns
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$M_1$} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{$M_2$} \\
    \cmidrule{1-1}
    \cmidrule{2-4}
    \cmidrule{5-10}
i   & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
r_i & 170 & 0 & 130 & 170 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 130 & 0 \\
\int_0^T g_i(x(t))
    & 204 178.8 & 580.7 & 580.7 & 45 840.7 & 158 338.1 & 580.7 & 0 & 580.7 & 0 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes! That looks amazing